# Why are some time zones returned by GetSystemTimeZones not found by FindSystemTimeZoneById?

Tags: c#, .net

I've got an odd problem I can't seem to resolve. When I call `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones` on my Win 7 x64 machine I get 101 results. When I call `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` on each of these and pass the StandardName attribute of the TimeZoneInfo object, 3 of them throw TimeZoneNotFoundException.

Here's a sample:

```
var tzs = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();

foreach (var timeZoneInfo in tzs.OrderBy(t => t.BaseUtcOffset))
{
  try
  {
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneInfo.StandardName);
  }
  catch (TimeZoneNotFoundException)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(timeZoneInfo.DisplayName + "|" + timeZoneInfo.StandardName + "|" + timeZoneInfo.BaseUtcOffset);
  }
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

This has trouble finding "Coordinated Universal Time", "Jerusalem Standard Time" and "Malay Peninsula Standard Time". Taking a case like Malaysia, I can see an entry for it when I look at the available time zones in my regional settings, although it's showing the DisplayName attribute rather than the StandardName:

[image: Time zones]

However, I can't see it under either name when browsing the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones

What's going on here? Why can't the Malaysia time zone be loaded by name?

Please no alternative time zone implementations using other libraries - I just want to get to the bottom of this issue for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid.aspx) method accepts the time zone id as parameter. You're using `timeZoneInfo.StandardName` instead.

It seems, that for these 3 zones values for [`TimeZoneInfo.StandardName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.standardname.aspx) and [`TimeZoneInfo.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx) properties are different. Using this:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneInfo.Id);
```

will solve the issue.

Comment: As weird as my code looks in retrospect (i.e. missing the painfully obvious), it's also odd that only 3 out of 101 TZs have a different ID to the standard name! Turns out Malaysia is "Singapore Standard Time". There you go!

Comment: @alex Do we have TimeZoneInfo.ID as a valid property?

Comment: I don't have a timezone id? where is this coming from?

Comment: @Andrew you can get the list of all time zones by using `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()`

Comment: There is no TimeZoneInfo.ID property in Windows 11.