# local time zone is not part of system time zones

Tags: c#, .net, timezone, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.net scheduling framework.
When I add a rule it uses `TimeZoneInfo.Local` to get the local time zone.

When I want to delete a rule for some reason it searches the time zone in system times zones by id, using:

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById
```

Usually this works fine, but I have one client with windows server 2008R2,
configured to be in Jerusalem standard time.

So in this case TimeZoneInfo.Local returns : "Jerusalem standard time"
But this is not a key in the registry , it should be: "Israel Standard time"
This causes the entire action to fail.
What's up with that? That makes no sense to me...

Comment: I found the following thread regarding this issue.  It seems to be caused by a missing or failed OS patch. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fca2f4c1-7b6e-4f19-8ca1-9cf176c74205/timezoneinfo-returns-different-id-values-for-israel-standard-time?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: Great lead, thanks. Do you know what SP solves this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't.

Comment: Downloading latest SP and time zone updates didn't work. Had to write a trigger after insert/update to change the time zone id as it is stored in the DB. Thanks for that, Microsoft :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because something is using the TimeZoneInfo.StandardName instead of the TimeZoneInfo.ID. For all timezones these values are identical, with the exception of 3 timezones, and "Jerusalem Standard Time" is one of those 3.

See the following link for the full explanation:
[Why are some time zones returned by GetSystemTimeZones not found by FindSystemTimeZoneById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225701/why-are-some-time-zones-returned-by-getsystemtimezones-not-found-by-findsystemti)